# Why sequences exist in function spaces(and more general spaces) eg. f_n in C[0,1]

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

In the book I am reading about Functional analysis, there is an algorithm for finding if some space is Banach.

1) search for element (x) in the space that we suspect to be the limit of ($x_n$)

2) check that x is element of X ....

For example we want to show that C[0,1] is complete equipped with supremum norm. The proof goes like this:
Let $x_n$ be Cauchy sequence in C[0,1] ... then we find x and show that x is indeed continuous function.

My question is - Why we can choose(find) a sequence ($x_n$) in the space. How do we know it exist for sure. How are we sure that there exists sequences in more abstract spaces(other than $R, R^n$)?

Comment: This might be a bit pedantic, but here goes: To prove that a space is complete, you have to show that every Cauchy sequence in it converges. So if there would be no sequences in the space, there would also be no Cauchy sequences, and you would be done. Also, if you just pick a fixed $x \in X$, then the constant sequence $(x)_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$ is a (Cauchy) sequence in $X$.

Comment: So the moral of the story is that if the space has at least one element at the very least we can just take the constant sequence?

Comment: Found the same question here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2396660/why-can-we-say-let-x-n-be-a-cauchy-sequence-in-x?rq=1 
I was not able to find it before.